# How to find something that does not exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I'm in desperate need of some help here.

My problem is this: There are two tables in my database, `tblSubmission` and `tblStudent`. `tblStudent` is linked with `tblSubmission` by the `student_id` key. Some of the rows in `tblStudent` have been deleted, and are therefore unlinked to their row in `tblSubmission`.

What I need to do is compare the two tables, and find the `student_id`'s that exist in `tblSubmission`, but NOT in `tblStudent`, but the results from `tblSubmission` have to have a column where `app_id` equals 358.

Checking through these rows manually is not an option since there are thousands of them. I've tried many queries already, using the most SQL I know and clauses like NOT EXISTS and NOT IN, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show all records in tblSubmission that have not a correlated record in tblStudent:

```
SELECT tblSubmission.*
FROM tblSubmission left join tblStudent on tblSubmission.student_id = tblStudent.student_id
WHERE tblStudent.student_id is null
      AND app_id = 358
```

or also:

```
SELECT tblSubmission.*
FROM tblSubmission
WHERE student_id not in (select student_id from tblStudent)
      AND app_id = 358
```

Comment: These queries work great, but can I further limit them to where app_id in tblSubmission is equal to 358? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @user1631077 yes i was updating my answer...now it should be okay!

Comment: I'm sure your queries are fine, but for some reason they're not returning anything now, but the applications with those student_id's do exist (my boss can still see them). Any suggestions? We're basically trying to find the student_id's so we can recreate the rows in tblStudent, if that makes sense.

Comment: If you're not getting any records then it's because you don't have any submissions without students. Get a submission ID from your boss, find the student id in the table and check for the student record for that id.

Comment: @user1631077 queries should be okay... if they don't return anything it's because all records with app_id=358 are correlated correctly. Do you have some deleted ids? If you have, you could check on both tables, but i think the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: I'm not sure which deleted ids you are talking about... the rows in tblStudent? The problem is that the rows have been deleted from tblStudent, so what links the two tables (student_id) is gone.

Comment: @user1631077 does your boss still can see some student_id that have been deleted? you could check if you can those ids in submission or student table.. or maybe ther have been deleted in another table that correlates id with something else... without knowing the structure of the database there's not much more that i can suggest...

Comment: Unfortunately my boss can't see the student_id's that have been deleted. I've looked through all the tables and haven't been able to find anything that correlates... but I'm going to keep looking. Thank you for your help! I appreciate it.

Comment: @fthiella it turns out your code was working correctly. The student_id's had been recycled and became associated with news submissions in the table, so that is why your code stopped finding results. Thank you for your help!